# How to resolve this mypy Incompatible types error of nested dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, mypy

I have following annotated dictionary:

```py
stage_specs: dict[str, dict[str, str | dict[str, str]]] = {
    'stage_name': {
        'handler': 'handler_name',
        'graph_component_name': 'STAGE_NAME',
        'query_params': {
            'compression': 'lz4',
        },
    },
}
```

Also I have a function

```py
def join_params(params: dict[str, str]) -> str:
```

Which is called in such way:

```
joined_query_param = join_params(stage_specs[stage_name]['query_params'])
```

But mypy yields such error `error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "Union[str, Dict[str, str]]", variable has type "Dict[str, str]")`. Is there any opportunities to resolve this problem?

Comment: Do your keys in `stage_specs` (or, more likely, dicts in its values) convey a semantic meaning? If they do, you probably want a [`TypedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypedDict). When you try to type such structures as `dict[str, union_of_all_possible_values]`, you always get such troubles, immediate or deferred. If it's important or part of some public API - use `TypedDict` to define the shape (or even `Pydantic` to add runtime config validation). If not - fire and forget, `dict[str, Any]` looks like a perfect type for such dictionary.

Comment: I've redefined `str | dict[str, str]` as `Any` and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated by the type annotation `dict[str, str | dict[str, str]]`, `stage_specs[stage_name]['query_params']` can be either a string or a dictionary, You need to handle both cases: when `query_params` is a string and when it's a dictionary.

```
def join_params(params: dict[str, str | dict[str, str]]) -> str:
    if isinstance(params, dict):
        # If params is a dictionary, join its values
        return ','.join(params.values())
    else:
        # If params is a string, simply return it
        return params

joined_query_param = join_params(stage_specs[stage_name]['query_params'])
```

OUTPUT:

```
lz4 
# Assuming a specific stage name like stage_name = 'stage_name'
```